# Why do TikZ help lines appear black in PDF?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is it that TikZ `help lines` are rendered `very thin` and `gray` (as desired) in DVI, but appear black and of normal thickness in PDF? This is true even of the TikZ manual itself.  My Adobe Reader is up-to-date.  Is there any way to make the help lines render properly in PDF?

Comment: Your problem probably is viewer-dependent. Do the help lines still appear black and thicker than they should if you  try zooming in on the tikzpicture?

Comment: With “My Adobe Reader is up-to-date” you speak of version 1.0.5? I’m quite sure, you have activated the option "Display thin lines more distinctly” (or the like, in my German version it reads “Dünne Linien deutlicher darstellen”), it is found in preferences for page view.

Comment: @Speravir That was precisely the problem. Thank you for resolving this long-perplexing issue.  For the benefit of others, the Adobe Reader pathway is Edit->Preferences->Page Display->Enhance Thin Lines (uncheck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause for this is quite probably a default setting in Adobe Reader:

Go into “Edit” –> “Preferences”, and in section “Page Display” uncheck option “Enhance Thin Lines” (valid at least for Adobe Reader XI).

*<sup>The English names thankfully provided by the OP after being pointed to.</sup>*